# Visualize my matplotlib output

Tags: matplotlib

I run a several code and get

```
Draw = pf.plot_drawdown_periods(returns, top=5).set_xlabel('Date')
type(Draw)
<matplotlib.text.Text at 0x7fb063733f90>
```

How can make my result visible in different ways?

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly call `pyplot.show()` to display the graphics.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pf.plot_drawdown_periods(returns, top=5).set_xlabel('Date')
plt.show()
```